# How to create partitioned table from other tables in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, create-table, partition

I am looking to create a table from an existing table in Amazon Athena. The existing table is partitioned on partition_0, partition_1, and partition_2 (all strings) and I would like this partition to carry over. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable
AS
Select x, partition_0, partition_1, partition_2 
FROM existingTable T
PARTITIONED BY (partition_0 string, partition_1 string, partition_2 string)
```

Trying to run this gives me an error at the FROM line, saying `"mismatched input 'by'. expecting: '(', ',',"`.... `Status code: 400; error code:invalidrequestexception`
Not sure what syntax I am missing here.

Comment: Did you try the simpler: PARTITIONED BY partition_0, partition_1 , partition_2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax for creating new tables:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
WITH (
  format = 'parquet',  
  external_location = 's3://example-bucket/output/', 
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['partition_0', 'partition_1', 'partition_2']) 
AS SELECT * FROM existing_table
```

See the documentation for more examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example-partitioned